# Easily set and get data between object structures in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

Warning.  This is a total newbie question for Groovy..  I'm from a Java background and I don't want to do it that way, unless I must.

I'd like to create either a mapping that will traverse one object graph easily between another object graph.

Like:

```
customer.contact.address.identifier = incomingContact.location.address.idCode
```

Both of the above object structures are completely different, with sometimes different data types.  In the above snippet, identifier is a Long, and idCode is a String.  Also, some of the objects are null, so I want to create sturctures on the fly.

How can this be done better with groovy's features of closures and more functional programming?

I was originally thinking inheritence or reflection solutions to minimize if/else conditions and instanceof based programming.

Any thoughts.

Here's some pseudo code that I started which already has smells of java:

Method call:

```
customer.contact.address.identifier = convert(incomingContact.location.address.idCode)
```

And here's the method:

```
Long convert(Object fromObject) {

    //example usage that were prototyping for this method (generically)    
    //fromObject = Long.valueOf(5);
    println "convert has: [" + fromObject + "]"
    if(fromObject != null) {

      return fromObject;
    }

    return null;
 }
```

The above snippet has complexity and problems in itself.  For one, it errors out when I want to set back the calling structure a null object, but a "Long".

The immediate error is:

groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: customer.contact.address.setIdentifier() is applicable for argument types: (null) values: [null]

My alternative thought is to use a mapping tool such as: http://dozer.sourceforge.net/ and allowing it to handle traversal of both graphs, but it's java again, which I wanted that groovy dynamic type solution.

Comment: Do you have some sort of pseudocode or something that explains what you want a bit clearer?

Comment: Updated, hope it helps understand my java to groovy confusion.  I could easily find the java reflection way, like apache commons, but I'm learning groovy.  thx..

Comment: Your code above doesn't make a lot of sense, it will always return a non-null `fromObject` even if it's type is not `Long` (the declared return-type of the method)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you simply want to bind properties from one object to another, Groovy's features won't help you much. Something like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/) might be worth a look.

BTW, here's a Groovier way to write the code above:

```
Long convert(fromObject) {

  println "convert has: [" + fromObject + "]"
  fromObject as Long
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm currently trying that out now as an alternative.  I was hoping to find some groovy based way of easily accessing deeply nested object structures in groovy with reflection and closures.  Maybe that's easier by just using Doozer w/Java and returning back the objects.  Nice to have that crosscutting code with groovy and java.

Comment: There's no reason why your code that uses Dozer has to be Java, you can call any Java library from Groovy code

Comment: FYI - We did end up using Groovy with Dozer (java) integrated to do the merge of XMLBeans from one object to the next.  It was much cleaner to use Dozer as of right now.  Thx.